# convert List<string> into Sobject

Tags: apex

I am having a list of string as follows:

```
List<String> str=new List<String>();
str.add('Post1');
str.add('Post2');
str.add('Post3');
```

I want to insert the above values into account object i.e account name=tcs and so on. I know I cant do it directly so I need help.

Comment: Your request is not clear - do you want to insert these 3 strings into 3 different accounts or the whole list into one account field?

Comment: I want to insert the 3 strings into 3 different accounts

Comment: @Tusharv answer!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like

```
List<account> accList = new List<account>();
afor(string s : str)
{
  accList.add(new Account(Name = s));// fill other required fields as well
}
insert accList;
```

Comment: How come I missed this? Many thanks, its working.....